# How do i make macros available to load-file in Clojure?

Tags: namespaces, clojure

Suppose you have the following code:

```
(ns foo)

(defmacro defproject [project-name version & args]
 ...
)

(defn read-project ([file]
    (load-file file)))
```

**Update**: The full code can be found at https://github.com/derkork/intellij-leiningen-plugin/blob/master/src/de/janthomae/leiningenplugin/leiningen/LeiningenProjectFile.clj

Now i call read-project on a file "project.clj" that has the following contents:

```
(defproject de.janthomae/leiningenplugin "1.0.0-SNAPSHOT"
  ...
)
```

And I get the following error message

```
java.lang.Exception: Unable to resolve symbol: defproject in this context (project.clj:1)
 at clojure.lang.Compiler.analyze(Compiler.java:4420)
 at clojure.lang.Compiler.analyze(Compiler.java:4366)
 at clojure.lang.Compiler$InvokeExpr.parse(Compiler.java:2828)
 at clojure.lang.Compiler.analyzeSeq(Compiler.java:4594)
 at clojure.lang.Compiler.analyze(Compiler.java:4405)
 at clojure.lang.Compiler.analyze(Compiler.java:4366)
```

That tells me it doesn't find my defproject macro. And I am totally clueless why it is that way, since the macro is defined just a few lines ahead. Do I need to export it somehow so it can be seen from files which are loaded using load-file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

project.clj doesn't indeed know where to look for foo/defproject. So if you are on repl, you can do

```
user> (in-ns 'foo)
foo> (read-project "project.clj")
```

This will run code from project.clj inside foo namespace, where defproject is defined. Or you can place (in-ns 'foo) inside project.clj. Result will be the same.

But you can also write something like this in project.clj:

```
(foo/defproject ...)
```

This will call defproject inside your current namespace when you run (foo/read-project "project.clj").

---

### update

from test_uberjar.clj:

```
(def project (binding [*ns* (the-ns 'leiningen.core)]
               (read-project "test_projects/sample_no_aot/project.clj")))
```

from test_deps.clj:

```
(:use [leiningen.core :only [read-project defproject]] ...)
```

So, defproject is always available when doing load-file.

Comment: I am not in a REPL, and adding the namespace to project.clj is not possible. I am trying to read Leiningen project files in my application and their format cannot be changed :(

Comment: I had a look at technomancy's implementation of this in Leiningen itself: https://github.com/technomancy/leiningen/blob/master/src/leiningen/core.clj  (Line 106). I wonder why it works there, but does not work in mine.

Comment: The binding [*ns* ... stuff seems to do the trick. I wonder why he doesn't need to do it in core.clj, actually the setup there is quite similar. Anyways, thank you very much :)